# is there an equivalent __reload__ function as to __import__?

Tags: python, import, reload

I only know the module name during runtime, and as such this is how it looks like:-

```
a = 'mymodule'
__import__(a)
```

but along the way, when mymodule.py is changed, i wanna reload it again.
is there a command like

```
__reload__(a)
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It's `reload(module)`. See the [python modules documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) (section 6.1) and the [library builtin functions reference](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html).

The argument is a module object, not a string so you must import it first.

```
mymodule = __import__('mymodule')
reload(mymodule)
```

Comment: As of python 3.2, the `reload` function is in [the imp library](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/imp.html#imp.reload).